# Content inside iframe redirects but not the whole page

Tags: html, css

So I have a column which has this code inside:

```
<div class="cat">
  <iframe src="sidebar.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>
```

and the this is a line inside "sidebar.html" :

```
<th target="_top" onclick="window.location='http://example.com'">example</th>
```

(keep in mind that this is a part of a table)

when I click on the word "example" it does actually redirect to where it should but thats only visible inside the iframe

I want to redirect the WHOLE page instead to www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Just only add "parent." before window.location:

```
<th target="_top" onclick="parent.window.location='http://example.com'">example</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`window.top.location.href = "http://www.newurl.com";`

to change the URL of the parent page.

A simple redirect will only work inside the iframe.